# How to identify Excel cell borders with Python?

Tags: python, excel

I am collecting rows from a large number of Excel files. Each file has a table with random number of rows. The last row might be followed by some text outside of the table.

How can I use the bottom border to identify the end of the table?

I used empty cells to identify table ends, which did not work out well.

Comment: I think you at least need to tell us which library you are using to read the excel file, before anyone can give meaningful answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by the horizontal border but in one of my past projects, I used pandas to do the job - it reads from Excel directly into a dataframe. I would suggest you to give it a shot. If you can get the entire page onto the dataframe, you will only need to handle null rows after that.

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepath) # Pandas ExcelFile object
df = xl.parse(sheetname) # Extracts data from the target sheet into a dataframe
```